# How to clear PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, pagedlist

I need to clear PagedListAdapter.

I've tried:

```
photoAdapter.currentList.clear() // Unsupported operation
```

also:

```
photoAdapter.onCurrentListChanged(list) // How to pass an empty list here?
```

Comment: Have you tried passing empty list in `submitList` ?

Comment: Nope. What do you mean? I think it requires a parameter

Comment: `submitList(listOf<>())` when u want to clear the list.

Comment: It doesn't work. Type mismatch.

Comment: submitList(null) clears list data